# Windows background issue with two screens

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, resolution, desktop-customization

I'm running Windows Vista 64-bit on a HP Compaq 6510b laptop with an external screen attached.

- The built-in screen has a resolution of 1400x900.
- The external screen has a resolution of 1920x1200.

Any background image that I set is shown with a maximum size of 1400x900, so it's not possible to fill the background of the big screen.

Is there a solution so that either the big screen also shows the full image or I could set separate background images per screen like on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure that the Picture Position setting is set to "Fit to screen" in Control Panel > Personalization > Desktop Background. I have a very similar setup, but am not seeing the same issue as you.

Comment: Alright thanks. I retried all the options and finally found one that fit. Strange I've had this problem.

Comment: This won't take into account aspect ratios of the pictures / monitors, and can potentially cause warped backgrounds.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a different picture on the different monitor with a tool like [**UltraMon**](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/wallpaper.asp).
In your case, the same picture with 2 different sizes.

(Tongue-in-cheek comment: "some" might insist that "[Your Desktop Is Not a Destination](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000963.html)"...)

Comment: sad to say, but even in this day and age of Windows 7, decent multi-monitor support is still lacking. UltraMon really fills a much-appreciated gap.

Answer (score 3):

[DisplayFusion](http://www.binaryfortress.com/displayfusion/) also supports multi-monitors and has a free version.

Comment: Its a great app :)